# Function returning a vec with prime factors of number

Tags: performance, rust, primes, factors

See code below and my comment with questions:

```rs
pub fn factors(n: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut m = n; // is it possible to convert n to a mutable type without using another variable?
    let mut a:Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
    while m % 2 == 0 {
        m /= 2;
        a.push(2);
    }
    // in C we can just write for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(m); i+= 2) ... just saying... and C is not even as fast as python to code... am I really doing it right??
    for i in (3..((m as f64).sqrt() as usize + 1usize)).step_by(2) { 
        while m % i as u64 == 0 { // is there a way to avoid all the casts to u64
            a.push(i as u64);
            m /= i as u64;
        }
    }
    if m > 2 {
        a.push(m);
    }
    return a;
}
```

- Is it possible to convert n to a mutable type without using another variable?
- The C equivalent of the main loop use twice less ink. Is Rust so verbose by design?
- Is there a way to avoid all the casts to u64
- any other insight welcome

Comment: Your while loop is infinite, because m never changes. Does this code have a copy-paste error?

Comment: The first while loop

Comment: copy/paste, I edit

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
pub fn factors(n: u64) -> Vec<u64> {
    let mut m = n; // is it possible to convert n to a mutable type without using another variable?
```

use `pub fn factors(mut n: u64)` to allow the parameter to be mutable

```
    let mut a:Vec<u64> = Vec::new();
```

You don't need `: Vec<u64>`, rust will infer it.

```
    while m % 2 == 0 {
        m /= 2;
        a.push(2);
    }


    // in C we can just write for (int i = 3; i <= sqrt(m); i+= 2) ... just saying... and C is not even as fast as python to code... am I really doing it right??
    for i in (3..((m as f64).sqrt() as usize + 1usize)).step_by(2) {
```

Generally speaking, Rust is less verbose than C, but you've hit one of the major exceptions. Rust is pickier about types, it won't let you mix and match different numeric types. But we can make some improvements here.

- You don't need `1usize` just use 1.
- You can also use `3 ..= (m as f64).sqrt() as usize` (..= includes the end)

Alternatively, you could reverse the check:

```
for index in (3..).step_by(2).take_while(|i| i * i <= m)
```

I'm not sure if that's better or not.

```
        while m % i as u64 == 0 { // is there a way to avoid all the casts to u64
            a.push(i as u64);
            m /= i as u64;
        }
```

You need casts because you are being inconsistent about your types. If you change the `usize` in the for loop to `u64` there will be no need for casts.

```
    }
    if m > 2 {
        a.push(m);
    }
    return a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much Winston! Just a quick question, in C, even though most of the time the compiler would optimize the following with optimization flags, it is better to compute an expression outside of loop or when it changes, what about Rush for `(m as f64).sqrt()` ?

Comment: Also how comes index are only implemented for usize and not for u8,u16,u32,u64 etc? Would it be a breaking change?

Comment: In Rust, `3 .. .(m as f64).sqrt()` is evaluated once before the loop starts. It's not like C where the expressions are repeatedly evaluated. So there is no optimization reason to move the sqrt calculation.

Comment: As for indexes, I think it follows from Rust's general practice of not allowing implicit type conversions. `usize` has a size depending on your architecture and thus isn't compatible with any of the types. But I really haven't looked closely at the rationale for that decision.